Floating button in the bottom right corner of a WhatsApp group chat: sound-wave icon, no clear action
I am using WhatsApp and I'm in the UK.
A new floating button has appeared in the bottom right corner of all my group chats.

It is round and it displays an icon that seems sound-related. Neither tapping nor holding it seem to have any obvious effect, apart from the transient color change for feedback.
It only appears when the screen is entirely scrolled down, and it gets replaced with the "jump to the end" icon when scrolling up.

Besides its apparent lack of function, it's also inconveniently placed, as it overlaps with checkmarks and reaction emojis if the last message was sent by me.
What is this button and what does it do?

Edit: it has disappeared after an update on December 5th. I'm still curious what it was supposed to be.

Its not on mine.  So it must one of your settings

I have the same button on every group, 2 members or 200 members.

I didn't experience/notice this, but possibly related to the Meta AI update.

As mentioned by Andrew, it is from Meta AI or Search.
If you click/press in its edit box, the symbol will appear.  I cant make it float.  On my phone, it is always in the Meta AI editbox.  It wont let me take a screenshot of it, it becomes hidden.

Meta AI on whatsapp is not available in my country.
My floating button could not be interacted with, and neither it, nor Meta AI (which, as I said, I don't have) had an edit box.
Thanks for attempting an answer, but this doesn't have the elements to convince me that we are talking about the same thing.

Ok, but I see that icon in Meta.  Obviously it was a bug in your case.  It disappears when I try to take a screenshot.
